# How to remove linux mint?

Tags: windows-7, linux, linux-mint, mbr

I've windows 8 and Linux mint both installed on my system , Now I want to remove both Linux mint and windows 8 and install windows 7 from a USB flash drive .

1. I don't know where the Linux mint files are
2. When I boot from the windows 7 USB drive , I can't install windows 7, it says the following :

   ```
   Error: Windows cannot be installed to Disk 0 Partition 1. (Show details)
   ```

   Details:

   > Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GTP disks. Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.

So my question is how to safely remove Linux mint and restore NTFS filesystem without losing any files on any of the partitions ? (I have no problem losing all files stored in the windows partition "C" )

Comment: If you want to install Windows 7 over Mint then your only option is to format the partition used by Mint.  The files can be backed up in any number of ways.

Answer (score 1):

You need gparted live: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

You should be able to view and edit partitions. Once you can see which is which you should be able to reformat a partition to allow you to install win7

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove both installed operating systems, the easiest thing to do would be to backup your data and then reformat the drive using the windows 7 installer. There is no way of changing a partition's filesystem without loosing the data on the partition.

I could give you more detailed information if you posted your partition details. In Linux, you can see these by running this command in a terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

You should see something like this (the following is from my system):

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    30801919    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30801920   194643539    81920810    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       194643601   976773119   391064759+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       194643603   198836504     2096451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda6       342951936   960387071   308717568   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       198840320   342949887    72054784   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       960389120   976773119     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

As you can see, in my case I have two NTFS partitions. One is a tiny system restore partition and the other has my Windows installation.

If you do *need* to switch to a GTP partition table, you will have to reformat the drive, remove all partitions and repartition it to use GTP. The easiest way to do this would be to boot into a [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) live session as suggested by [matpol](https://superuser.com/a/547393/151431) and delete all partitions. You should then be able to partition using the win7 installer.